# Check after f.seek(mid) if the pointer is at the start of new line or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, seek

I'm opening a text file and doing a:

`f.seek(mid) where mid= (0+f.seek(0,2))//2`

Now I want to check if the read pointer is at the starting of a new line or not?

Based on that I discard `f.readline()` if pointer is not at the start and read a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trivial solution would be to do `f.seek(mid-1)` and check if `f.read(1) == "\n"` or not.